# Can ubuntu be put on a USB with wubi?

Tags: wubi

I want to install ubuntu onto my 64gb USB and I want to use wubi. I am running windows 7. Is this possible? Also is the ubuntu on the wubi 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Why do you want to use Wubi? You can install Ubuntu on a stick without using Wubi. I have Ubuntu installed on an external hard disk (same procedure for a USB stick). If you remove the Wubi requirement I will post an answer.

Comment: Good point @ToDo :-) - but it can run rather slowly of some USB sticks... Anyway, there is a tutorial [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/move-wubi-to-a-usb-flash-drive/) for moving Wubi to a USB, and two more [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2084736) and [here](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/23/install-ubuntu-11-04-on-external-hard-disk/) to install a normal Ubuntu distribution to a USB.